# Which part of the rails MVC framework would redirected authentication be located?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authentication, openid-connect

For example, if I wanted to use OpenID Connect to authenticate a user on a seperate server (Proxy authentication server) than the server hosting my rails app, where would the code to redirect this use be located?

I am trying to test authentication on a rails app (my first time using rails framework) and I am not sure if I am being authenticated, as I am upgrading dependencies with new ones for the AWSSSL Proxy, I am trying to find out a way to test authentication.

Comment: Are you using something like [AuthLogic](https://github.com/binarylogic/authlogic) or [Devise](https://github.com/heartcombo/devise)? If you have an external authentication layer maybe you need to bridge back out to that using some other mechanism. SASL? SAML? LDAP? Depends on what AWSSSL uses.

Comment: Redirect logic goes in a controller.

Comment: Yes I am using LDAP for authentication